# Magmi import of related products successful on front-end, but products missing on back-end

Tags: magento2, magmi

I did an import of related products (re_skus) using Magmi and Magento 2.2.3 recently, and on the front-end the data is correct. However on the back-end, only 2 related products are shown as being attached to the main product. I checked all main products from my CSV and it's the same for all -- just 2 related products in the back-end (but there are really many more that are related). No errors or anything in Magmi console.

I tried reindexing, clearing caches, etc. but still no success. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you have any luck solving this?